# Unable to automatically pick foreign key from modelform

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, modelform

I am working on a product app on Python 2.7 / Django 1.7.

I have a model for product namely 'product_profile' and I want to allow my customer (end user) to ask any thing regarding specific products using a form.

However I am unable to allow user to automatically select the product (foreign key) and the customer has to select from a drop-down which quite irrational. I have also assigned the foreign key in url-variable.

here is my code:

#### MODEL.PY

```
class ProductProfile(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    generation = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    processor = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ram = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0)
    hdd = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    optical_drive = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    display = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    card_reader = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    blue_tooth = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    web_cam = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    warranty = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    condition = models.TextField()
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=update_Product_image_filename)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)

    # Override th __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name


class Customer_ps_contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128 )
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductProfile)
    message = models.TextField()
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: 

'+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True, max_length=15) # validators should be a 

list

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### FORM.PY

```
class Customer_ps_contactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer_ps_contact
        product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProductProfile.objects.all(),
widget=forms.HiddenInput())

        fields = ('name','email', 'product','subject','message', 'phone_number')
```

#### VIEWS.PY

```
def product_inquiry(request, product_id):
    product = ProductProfile.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #form = Customer_ps_contactForm(request.POST, initial = {'product': product})

        #form = Customer_ps_contactForm(initial = {'product': product.id})

        form = Customer_ps_contactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            form_data_dict = form.cleaned_data
            print form_data_dict['product']
            mail_customer_enquriy(form_data_dict) # Function to send email to admin
            thank_u_customer(form_data_dict) # Function to send email to customers

            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.product = product
            form.save()
            return home(request)
        else:
            print ("form is not valid")
            print (form.errors)
    else:
        form = Customer_ps_contactForm()

    context_dict = {'form':form, 'product': product}

    return render(request, 'product/product_inquiry2.html',context_dict)
```

#### URL Patterns

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^inquiry/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.product_inquiry, name='price'), # Only relevent url given
       )
```

#### Template : product_inquiry2.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block body_block %}
{% block title %}Product Inquiry{% endblock %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h2 style="font-weight:bold">Enquiry regarding '{{product.product_name}}'</h2>
        <hr>
        <form id="contact_form" method="post" action=""/>

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form | crispy }}

            <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right " type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit the Message" />
        </form>

    </div>
</div>





{% endblock %}
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You are already assigning the product manually in the is_valid block, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what the product is from the id in the url, so there's no need to include it in your form.

To check that the product exists in the database, you can use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut.

```
def product_inquiry(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(ProductProfile, pk=product_id)
```

Then leave out 'product' from your list of fields, and remove the `ModelChoiceField` with hidden input widget.

```
class Customer_ps_contactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer_ps_contact

        fields = ('name','email','subject','message','phone_number')
```

You are already setting the product when you save it, but it would be clearer to use the variable name `instance` to make it clearer what's going on. If you change your `mail_customer_enquriy` and `thank_u_customer` methods to use the instance instead of `cleaned_data`, then you won't have to do anything with `form.cleaned_data`.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.product = product
        instance.save()

        mail_customer_enquriy(instance) # Function to send email to admin
        thank_u_customer(instance) # Function to send email to customers

        return home(request)
```

Comment: Really it would be better to make those methods operate on the instance, rather than the cleaned_data dict.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that modelform is not validated if if I exclude the foreign_key i.e., product_profile.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed what do you mean the model form is not validated? Do you mean that the form has errors? In that case what errors do you get? Or do you mean that the `product_id` is not checked? In that case use `get_object_or_404` in the view.

Comment: Its fine now. I've been using 'exclude' and form was unable to save. You removed clean_data dict, what about data sanitization?

Comment: You are using a model form, so the data is validated when you call `form.is_valid()`. After saving the form, you can get the values from the instance e.g. `form.email`, so there is usually no need to access `form.cleaned_data` directly.